# Redirect URI parameter causes app to leave Facebook frame when authenticating

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I can see there are other similar topics, but they are old and in the world on Facebook any advice seems likely out of date after about a week!  So I wanted to check afresh.  My app is all working fine, and authenticating without any problems.  However after authenticating you are redirected outside of the Facebook frame.  I'm doing this with the PHP method, using the examples on their site.

```
top.location.href='http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...&redirect_uri=http://www.myhosting.com/'
```

Is this redirect_uri correct?  I know it is meant to match something in your app settings but they keep changing the names of everything - Is it meant to match my Canvas Page `https://apps.facebook.com/myappname/` or my Canvas URL `http://www.myhosting.com` ? As you can see I have got it matching the second, the Canvas URL.  If I try to make it match the Canvas Page I get an error (simply says `an error occurred`).  Can someone please confirm what exactly the `redirect_uri` is meant to match?

Answer (score 0):

Both will work, if you want the user to land on your canvas page after login, set the redirect_uri to your canvas page

{edit after comments below} - i'm absolutely sure this will work - set the redirect_uri to `http://apps.facebook.com/<your app namespace>` and the user will be directed back into your canvas app

Comment: That's not true, Canvas URL definitely doesn't work.  Not unless you purposefully want to leave the Facebook frame!  Which I doubt.  I discovered the problem, which isn't documented anywhere - unsurprisingly!  We hadn't decided on a name yet so hadn't supplied an "app namespace" which is used to make the Canvas Page.  The Canvas Page default is apps.facebook.com/YOURAPPID/ which works fine for most things but not for authentication.  You need to have the app namespace set.

Comment: @AimeeBaker: just notice your comment after posting the answer. Well, the "namespace" is a sudden change, really give me some headache several weeks ago.

Comment: did u solve the prob.my app also goes out of facebook frame.giving apps.facebook.com/code gives unknown error on redirection. :(